# Melpa upgrade ignores url-proxy-service

Tags: package-repositories, proxy

I use Emacs in a corporate environment behind a proxy.

I have customized `url-proxy-services`:

```lisp
 '(url-proxy-services
   (quote
    (("http" . "proxy:3128")
     ("https" . "proxy:3128"))))
```

I use the package tool:

```
(require 'package)
```

And I have customized the Melpa archives:

```lisp
 '(package-archives (quote (("melpa" . "http://melpa.org/packages/"))))
```

When I run `package-list-packages` I see the packages and the list gets updated. This means the proxy gets used for this.

But when I try to install a package, Emacs stalls:

```
Importing package-keyring.gpg...done
Package refresh done
2 packages can be upgraded; type ‘U’ to mark them for upgrading.
2 packages marked for upgrading.
Upgrade these 2 packages (groovy-mode-2.0, s-1.12.0)? y
Package menu: Operation started [Upgrading 2]
Contacting host: melpa.org:80
Quit
```

When I sniff the network with `tcpdump`, I can see packets send directly to some hosts on port 80. This matches the last message "Contacting host: melpa.org:80".

Why does Melpa ignore the proxy for the download? And how can I change this?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a bug in version 26. I just compiled 27 and it works as expected.